# Iterating through an array when there is a single element

Tags: grails, foreach, grails-orm

I have an array with value users:[Test1,Test2] and below is the code for iterating through the loop.

```
def usernames = params.users
usernames.each{itr->
println("array values:"+ itr);
}
```

Above solution works fine when there are multiple values.But when i pass only 1 value  users:Test3. Above code prints the value as separate characters:

```
T
E
S
T
3.
```

How to make the above code work for single values?

Comment: users should be users: [Test3] not users:Test3.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into Validation objects i.e. implements Validateable { classes - there is some magic stuff that happens where objects magically bind to end data types without you having to strictly specify like below answer params.list('object') instead you declare List<String> usernames in the validateable bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `params.list` to convert to list, like

```
List<String> usernames = params.list('users')
```